# Graph ODATA $filter startswith function does not work with List Items in Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

In graph explorer, I am trying to execute OData queries with the filter startswith on list items. All of the OData filter startswith functions I tried to return itemNotFound error. See an example below
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/lists('Documents')/Items?$filter=startswith(webURL, 'https') eq true

Graph explorer has Sites.ReadWrite.All scope.

Can someone point me to any documentation on the extent of OData features supported in Microsoft Graph?

Comment: There is a feature request open here, please upvote: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/aa3cdd9a-b9f3-ec11-a81b-000d3a00c008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint List API (and Graph API on drives/OneDrive API) do not support filtering or ordering results. As you may know, both SharePoint Document and OneDrive can be accessed by the Drive api. When Microsoft Graph sees a query parameter it doesn't expect, it simply ignoring the unknown filter parameter and returning us an unfiltered result. The drives api supports the **$expand, $select, $skipToken, $top, and $orderby**(orderby does not work on my side) OData query parameters to customize the response.

The currently available [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter-parameter) just states:

> Support for $filter operators varies across Microsoft Graph APIs.

The word **varies** might be the inference that these options are not totally supported across all products in Graph.

Comment: Worth noting that search is supported, as this may help in some circumstances 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http